# Counting of the threads of a Codename One app

Tags: codenameone

`Log.p("Active threads: " + Thread.activeCount(), Log.DEBUG);` logs a different threads count when the same Codename One app is run on different devices. I don't understand: if I don't use timers or network threads, all the app shouldn't run inside only one thread (the EDT)?

Thank you for any clarification.

*(This question is referred to Codename One only)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default generated code has 2 network threads which will open once a network request is made. Codename One also creates the EDT and will occasionally spawn a short lived thread to do a wait task e.g. for the various AndWait methods or for showing a dialog.

Other than that you would have the OS native EDT which in some OS's also includes another worker thread. GC thread which is also sometimes accompanied by a finalizer thread. You would also have task dedicated threads such as those for handling media, push etc.

Many of these threads would be idle and thus will have no noticeable impact on performance.